# Стилистика и пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

*Это даже не дурной характер, это нечто более серьёзное; и я даже знаю, что*.

Не слишком ли это громоздкая конструкция? Может, ***и я даже знаю, что*** лучше сделать отдельным предложением? Допустима ли постановка тире вместо запятой перед ***что***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По общим правилам ни запятой, ни тире в вашем примере ставить не нужно, т.к. придаточная часть усечена до одного союзного слова. Однако в условиях контекста, для логического выделения союзного слова, возможно постановка как запятой, так и тире. Что касается самой конструкции, то здесь надо учитывать, что это обыкновенная разговорная речь, где вполне допустимы такие конструкции.

Comment: В "и я даже знаю что" запятая не нужна, а если бы было "и я даже знаю что это" или "и я даже знаю что именно"?

Comment: Запятая не ставится  перед союзом что.  В предложении "и я даже знаю что это" - неполное придаточное, запятая ставится. А в предложении "и я даже знаю что именно" - запятая факультативна. В этих случаях перед союзом стоят частицы.  См.: Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по пунктуации. § 33. п.3.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж !

Answer (score 4):

Это даже не дурной характер, это нечто более серьёзное; и я, пожалуй, знаю чтО.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Не стоит два раза употреблять усилительное слово "даже", если это только не особый художественный прием.

2) Запятую лучше не ставить, что связано со структурой предложения: **нет паузы, логическое ударение падает только на союзное слово.

**Правило постановка запятой**

1) **Основная форма**: запятая не ставится

Я бы тоже хотел знать почему. Не знаю  почему,  но я его не понимал.  Всё это уж было когда-то, но только не помню когда. Меня упрекают, но я не знаю в чём. Меня спросили, куда я поеду летом, и я объяснил куда.

2) **Исключение**: запятая ставится, логическое выделение и глагола, и  союзного слова, наличие паузы

Что же надо делать?  Научите,  что.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, Vera!

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то, перед «что» запятая не нужна. Во-вторых, действительно, ваше предложение лучше оформить отдельно.